# how to add and delete values from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On console it should print the div id of particular div created in the form of array and each time div is created its value should be stored in array and whenever the div is deleted the value of corresponding div should be removed from array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to make a Division element.</p>

<button id="button" onclick="myFunctionTry()">Add</button>

<div id="myDIV">
</div>

<script>
var counter=1;
   function myFunctionTry()
   {

            var x = document.createElement("DIV");
            x.id="div"

            var z= document.createElement("button");
            z.id="btn";
            x.setAttribute("style", "border :1px solid;height: 250px; width: 250px; top: 741px; left: 491px; padding:10px; margin: 50px;");
            z.setAttribute("style", "background: #000 url(/home/subodh/Desktop/Widget/icon_incorrect.svg) no-repeat 0px 0px; height: 30px; width:40px; top: 6px; left: 4px; float: right; margin: 0px; padding:0px; clear: both; float:right;");

            x.appendChild(z);
            document.body.appendChild(x).appendChild(z);

            var divNumber = counter;
                counter++;
                var arr=[];
               arr.push(divNumber);

               console.log(arr);

            z.onclick = function remove(btn) 
            {
            x.parentElement.removeChild(x);
            var arr1=arr;
            console.log(arr1);
            }



   }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

how to get output as: [1] [1,2] [1,2,3]....... on running above mentioned code. M getn output as [1] [2] [3]......   . How can this be done using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your array variable outside of the function. See the below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to make a Division element.</p>

  <button id="button" onclick="myFunctionTry()">Add</button>

  <div id="myDIV">
  </div>

  <script>
    var counter = 1;
    var arr = [];

    function myFunctionTry() {

      var x = document.createElement("DIV");
      x.id = "div"

      var z = document.createElement("button");
      z.id = "btn";
      x.setAttribute("style", "border :1px solid;height: 250px; width: 250px; top: 741px; left: 491px; padding:10px; margin: 50px;");
      z.setAttribute("style", "background: #000 url(/home/subodh/Desktop/Widget/icon_incorrect.svg) no-repeat 0px 0px; height: 30px; width:40px; top: 6px; left: 4px; float: right; margin: 0px; padding:0px; clear: both; float:right;");

      x.appendChild(z);
      document.body.appendChild(x).appendChild(z);

      var divNumber = counter;
      counter++;

      arr.push(divNumber);

      console.log(arr);

      z.onclick = function remove(btn) {
        x.parentElement.removeChild(x);
        var arr1 = arr;
        console.log(arr1);
      }



    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```